Tikz with double headed stealth arrows
I am trying to tikz a picture that is the unfolded version of the Klein bottle with some added decorations.

This is what I have so far and I'm trying to figure out how to use stealth to draw the vertical orientation arrows with two arrowheads:

Here is the code I have so far
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}



\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
              \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth}}}
        ] 

        % % orientation arrows
     \draw[gray, postaction={decorate}] (-0.5,2.25) -- (0.5, 2.25);
     \draw[gray, postaction={decorate}] (-.5,-2.25) -- (0.5, -2.25);

\draw[decoration ={markings, mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.5cm with {\arrow{stealth}}}] (0,5)--(1,5); 


       


        
        % % fixed point set
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (-1.5,1.5) -- (0, 1.5);
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1.5) -- (0,1.5);
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (-1.5,0) -- (0,0);
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (0,0);
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (-1.5,-1.5) -- (0,-1.5);
        \draw[blue, postaction={decorate}] (1.5,-1.5) -- (0,-1.5);
        % \node[blue, anchor = north] at (2.25,2.25) {$M^G$};
        

        
        % % unstable trajectories
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5, 1.5);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5, -1.5);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0, 1.5) -- (0,0);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,-1.5) -- (0,0);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (1.5, 1.5);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (1.5, -1.5);
        
        % % critical points
        \node[anchor = north] at (-1.75, 0.25) {$a$};
        \draw[fill] (-1.5, 0) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (1.75, 0.25) {$a$};
        \draw[fill] (1.5, 0) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (-1.75, 1.75) {$b$};
        \draw[fill] (-1.5, 1.5) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (1.75, 1.75) {$b$};
        \draw[fill] (1.5, 1.5) circle (0.05);
        \draw[fill] (1.5, 0) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (-1.75, -1.25) {$b$};
        \draw[fill] (-1.5, -1.5) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (1.75, -1.25){$b$};
        \draw[fill] (1.5, -1.5) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (-0.2, 1.5) {$c$};
        \draw[fill] (0,1.5) circle (0.05);
        \node[anchor = north] at (-0.2, -1.5) {$c$};
        \draw[fill] (0, -1.5) circle (0.05);
         \node[anchor = north] at (-0.2, -0.05) {$d$};
        \draw[fill] (0, 0) circle (0.05);
        
       \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Dynamics on torus}
        \label{fig:dynamics on torus}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Representations of the upright torus and a possible choice of orientations.}
    \label{torus example}
\end{figure}


Thanks in advance!

Please reduce your code fragment to MWE which reproduce your problem.  (remove all what is not relevant to your problem) and extend fragment to small complete document, which we can test as it is.

like this:

By defining two arrows style the code is short and clear:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Stealth,
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
                          mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
                         },
               postaction={decorate}
              },
->>-/.style = {decoration={markings,
                         mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>>}}
                        },
               postaction={decorate}
              },
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep=1.2pt,
              label=#1}
                        ]
%  orientation arrows
\draw[->-,gray] (-0.5,2) -- ++ (1,0);
\draw[->-,gray] (-.5,-2) -- ++ (1,0);
%
\draw[->>-,blue] (-2.5,-0.5) -- ++ (0,1);
\draw[->>-,blue] ( 2.5, 0.5) -- ++ (0,-1);
%%%% fixed point set
\node (n11) [dot={left:$b$}] at (-1.5, 1.5) {};
\node (n12) [dot={left:$a$}] at (-1.5, 0.0) {};
\node (n13) [dot={left:$b$}] at (-1.5,-1.5) {};
%
\node (n21) [dot={below left:$c$}] at (0, 1.5) {};
\node (n22) [dot={below left:$d$}] at (0, 0.0) {};
\node (n23) [dot={below left:$e$}] at (0,-1.5) {};
%
\node (n31) [dot={right:$b$}] at (1.5, 1.5) {};
\node (n32) [dot={right:$a$}] at (1.5, 0.0) {};
\node (n33) [dot={right:$b$}] at (1.5,-1.5) {};
%%%%\emph{} arows
\foreach \y in {1,2,3}
{
    \draw[->-,blue] (n1\y) -- (n2\y);
    \draw[->-,blue] (n3\y) -- (n2\y);
}
%
\draw[->-] (n12) -- (n11);
\draw[->-] (n12) -- (n13);
%
\draw[->-] (n21) -- (n22);
\draw[->-] (n23) -- (n22);
%
\draw[->-] (n32) -- (n31);
\draw[->-] (n32) -- (n33);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As you can see, answer is focused just to drawing arrows.
** Edit:**
According to your comment, here is version with Stealth arrows heads with improved, i.e. centered anchors of heads. For this is employed ext.arrows of tikz-ext package (see code below). If you not liked it, just use standard tikz syntax as is done in the first example)
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                ext.arrows,     % loaded by "tikz-ext" package,
                                % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Centered Stealth,   % <--- changed type and centered position
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
                          mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
                         },
               postaction={decorate}
              },
->>-/.style = {decoration={markings,
                         mark=at position #1 % <--- adjustable arrow headposition
                                             with {\arrow{[sep=3pt]>>}}
                        },
               postaction={decorate}
              },
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep=1.2pt,
              label=#1}
                        ]
%  orientation arrows
\draw[->-,gray] (-0.5,2) -- ++ (1,0);
\draw[->-,gray] (-.5,-2) -- ++ (1,0);
%
\draw[->>-=0.7,blue] (-2.5,-0.5) -- ++ (0, 1);  % <--- changed mark psition
\draw[->>-=0.7,blue] ( 2.5, 0.5) -- ++ (0,-1);  % <--- changed mark psition
%%%% fixed point set
\node (n11) [dot={left:$b$}] at (-1.5, 1.5) {};
\node (n12) [dot={left:$a$}] at (-1.5, 0.0) {};
\node (n13) [dot={left:$b$}] at (-1.5,-1.5) {};
%
\node (n21) [dot={below left:$c$}] at (0, 1.5) {};
\node (n22) [dot={below left:$d$}] at (0, 0.0) {};
\node (n23) [dot={below left:$e$}] at (0,-1.5) {};
%
\node (n31) [dot={right:$b$}] at (1.5, 1.5) {};
\node (n32) [dot={right:$a$}] at (1.5, 0.0) {};
\node (n33) [dot={right:$b$}] at (1.5,-1.5) {};
%%%%\emph{} arows
\foreach \y in {1,2,3}
{
    \draw[->-,blue] (n1\y) -- (n2\y);
    \draw[->-,blue] (n3\y) -- (n2\y);
}
%
\draw[->-] (n12) -- (n11);
\draw[->-] (n12) -- (n13);
%
\draw[->-] (n21) -- (n22);
\draw[->-] (n23) -- (n22);
%
\draw[->-] (n32) -- (n31);
\draw[->-] (n32) -- (n33);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you, @Zarko! this indeed just boils down to defining arrows. I do like the stealth-styled arrows better and wonder if there is a way to use that instead? Would you happy to have an easy fix for this?

I figured it out! Just by replacing > = Straight Barb with > = Stealth did the trick! Thank you so much!

@cheeseboardqueen, please, clarify what is your problem? Just to define tip of arrows' heads or to have two successive  heads? About this your question is not quite clear. Your ketch show something close what I did in my answer. I'm pretty sure, that my answer solved your problem and significantly improve your code. So, you should consider to accept it ... BTW I add solution with desired type of arrows' heads.
